# Linked list not compounding during execution

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list that stores return instructions while parsing an assembly code file. As an explanation for the code, when encountering a call instruction the address of the next instruction is to be saved. When encountering a return instruction, the linked list is supposed to be traversed until it reaches a point when the next node is `NULL`. For some reason the code is not saving the return addresses. Might it have something to do with the recursion?

```
//function to create a node in linked list
struct ret_addr *return_address(cs_insn *insn, struct ret_addr *r) {
    struct ret_addr *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
    ret->address = insn->address + insn->size;
    ret->nxt_ret_addr = r;
    return ret;
}

//retrieve the data from the last node of the linked list
int return_val(struct ret_addr *r) {
    if(r == NULL)
        return 0;
    while(r->nxt_ret_addr != NULL) {
        r = r->nxt_ret_addr;
        return r->address;
    }
}

//parse assembly code
struct bb_data *disassemble_function_cfg(int startAddr, unsigned char *bytes, int end_section) {
    csh handle;
    cs_insn *insn;
    cs_detail *detail;
    size_t count;
    int stop_disasm = 0;

    struct ret_addr *r_data = malloc(sizeof(*r_data));
    count = cs_disasm(handle, bytes, end_section, startAddr, 1, &insn);

    detail = insn->detail;
    for(int n = 0; n < detail->groups_count; n++) {
        if(detail->groups[n] == X86_GRP_CALL) {
            stop_disasm = 1;
            r_data = return_address(insn, r_data);
        }
        else if(detail->groups[n] == X86_GRP_RET) {
            stop_disasm = 1;
            start_edge = return_val(r_data);
        }

    if(!stop_disasm)
        disassemble_function_cfg(insn->address + insn->size, bytes + insn->size, end_section);
    else
        return edges;
}
```

During an inital `call` instruction the return value is saved (checked by printing it out), but when reaching a return instruction the linked list is suddenly empty. My idea is that this is caused by the constant calls to `malloc`, but am unsure if that is a correct assumption.

Comment: `while(r->nxt_ret_addr != NULL) {
        r = r->nxt_ret_addr;
        return r->address;
    }` Huh? [this functions hould return **int**] `while(r->nxt_ret_addr != NULL) {
        r = r->nxt_ret_addr;
        return r->address;
    }` there issomthingwronghere.

Comment: you printed the same thing twice. I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `return_val` function : it does not modify the `r_data`value from the caller function `disassemble_function_cfg`.

There's also one little thing I assumed : since it is a call/return implementation, the linked list should behave as LIFO (last in first out). The `return_address` function fills the linked list by inserting in the head, so the `return_val` function should remove address from the head first : there's no need to read the list until reaching `NULL`.

Try this code :

```
//retrieve the data from the last node of the linked list
int return_val(struct ret_addr **r) {
    int ret_val;
    if (*r == NULL)
        return 0;
    ret_val = (*r)->address;
    *r = (*r)->nxt_ret_addr;
    return ret_val;
}
```

In the caller function :

```
    else if(detail->groups[n] == X86_GRP_RET) {
        stop_disasm = 1;
        start_edge = return_val(&r_data); // address of r_data, so it can be modified
    }
```

Comment: Even when putting in these changes to the code the return address is 0. When putting in a print statement at the very end (right before `return edges`) the program will segfault

Comment: Well, I don't really know what `start_edge` and `edges` are. According to your code, `start_edge` will receive the last `int`value `insn->address + insn->size`.